# Can i import a function for any existing arity?

Tags: elixir

Let's say i have module with a function having heads with different arity. Is there a way to import this function in another module for all the available arities (without being explicit)?

```
defmodule Math do
  def plus(a, b) do
  end

  def plus(a, b, c) do
  end

  def plus(a, b, c, d) do
  end
end

defmodule AdditiveCalculator do
  # Explicit import
  import Math, only: [plus: 2, plus: 3, plus: 4]

  # What i'm hoping for
  import Math, only: [plus: :all]
end
```

Comment: There is no variable amount of arguments in Erlang/Elixir. If you need summing longer lists of values, pass list of values to the function. This eliminates the need for "import all".

Comment: Of course if you want all the functions, just use `import Math` and don't use the `only:` option. That will give you all the functions in the module, which I don't think is exactly what you're asking for, but would work.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I  know,  there is no such functionality in Elixir.

See [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html) for more details.

---

EDIT:

@tkowal brings up a great point in a comment above.  If you're trying to sum variable lists of integers the right approach is to pass the argument as a list of integers and then work with that.  Like so:

```
defmodule T do
  def plus(l) when is_list(l), do: plus(l,0)
  defp plus([], acc), do: acc
  defp plus([item] = l, acc), do: acc + item
  defp plus([head|tail] = l, acc), do: plus(tail, acc+head)
end
```

Then to use it, call it like this:

```
T.plus([1,2,3,4])
#=> 10
```

Comment: Do you really need the `defp plus([item] = l, acc), do: acc + item` clause? `tail` of a single item list will be the empty list, so the other clauses will cover all scenarios, right?

Comment: That's a good point @CoderDennis.  I would need to double check that but I believe you're right.  Usually when I post code here, I do it more for a didactic purpose than necessarily something I'd actually use for production work.

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes an incorrect assumption about the nature of functions in Elixir. You say you have "a function having heads with different arity" and later "this function".

You don't have a single function with multiple heads. You actually have 3 different functions. Functions are identified by both name and arity. `plus/2`, `plus/3` and `plus/4` may share a name, but they are not the same function. See http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#identifying-functions

This is also why you need to explicitly list them out when specifying the `only` option on an `import`. You're importing those 3 distinct functions from the module.